# Concept relation between tangent vector of smooth function and the mapping of a vector to this smooth function

Tags: differential-geometry

If $f$ is a smooth function on a manifold $M$, mapping it to the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, and $v$ represents a vector on $M$ at a point $p$, does the mapping $v(f)\mid_p$ correspond to the tangent vector of $f$ at point $p$? Is that correct?

I think it is correct, but one of my friends thought the vector $v$ is just a vector on $M$, which may be related to the tangent vector of $f$ at point $p$, but not necessarily identical.

But I think this is just a view of choosing different coordinates. Is there any wrong with my understanding? I'd really appreciate some erudite to point out my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have multiple misconceptions, so let me try to address each of them.

On a smooth manifold $M$, there is no notion of a "tangent vector of $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$". Tangent vectors are, by definition, the objects which live in the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold, e.g. $v\in T_pM$ as you mentioned. A function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is not a smooth manifold, so it does not have tangent vectors, and there is no canonical way to associate a tangent vector(field) to a smooth function $f$.

What you can do with a function (and more generally a differential form), is differentiate. We have the exterior derivative, which abstractly is viewed as a mapping $d:C^\infty(M)\to\Omega^1(M)$. But the $1$-form $df\in\Omega^1(M)$ is really just the analogue of the directional derivative from vector calculus. There, you would have $v(f)|_p$ as the derivative of the function $f$ in the direction of $v$. Likewise, $df_p(v)=v(f)|_p$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$.

Now, in vector calculus, it is typical to view the derivative of a function as a vector, instead of a $1$-form. This implicitly uses the isomorphism between vector fields and $1$-forms which is given by the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Maybe this is what you mean when you say "tangent vector of $f$ at $p$", in which case, let's denote this by $(\nabla f)_p$. Such a notion does also exist on a smooth manifold $M$ - but not canonically. You have to choose a Riemannian metric $g$, which provides an isomorphism $\phi:TM\to T^*M$. Then one can define $\nabla f=\phi^{-1}(df)$. In vector calculus, one has $v(f)|_p=df_p(v)=(\nabla f)_p\cdot v$, and this becomes (basically by definition) $df_p(v)=g((\nabla f)_p,v)$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.

One final misconception to clear up before I answer your question: $v(f)|_p$ is just a real number, it is not a mapping. The mapping which can be associated to a function $f$ is its differential, which is a mapping between the tangent spaces $df_p:T_pM\to\mathbb{R}$. Once you evaluate it on a particular $v\in T_pM$ to get $v(f)|_p=df_p(v)\in\mathbb{R}$, it is just a real number, not a mapping.

So the answer to your question is: there is no canonical notion of a "tangent vector of $f$". If your intention was to say that the mapping $T_pM\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $v\mapsto v(f)|_p$ is the natural analogue of the directional derivative, then yes. This mapping is precisely $df_p$, which I described above. If you are asking instead whether, given any particular $v\in T_pM$, the expression $v(f)|_p$ should in any way be called the tangent vector of $f$, then you are definitely incorrect, and I hope the explanation above will clear up your confusion. If that was the case, your friend was probably referring to the expression $(\nabla f)_p\in T_pM$, and indeed, there is only one tangent vector which is the gradient of $f$ at $p$.